# How to prevent Outlook from removing closing parentheses when adding other email address with a display name

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-client

I have access to an alias for my email (associated to a google group).

When I try to add this email addresse as another email address that I can send emails from in Outlook, this seems to work properly at first.

[image]

[image]

However, when I send an email to myself using that *From* option, I always get that the email came from:

`My Name (Organisation`
(Notice the missing closing parenthesis)

I tried to use quotations like this :

`"My Name (Organisation)" <support@organisation.com>`

But I get the same result as before: `My Name (Organisation`

I even tried an escape character:
`"My Name (Organisation\)" <support@organisation.com>`

But I got this as a result: `My Name (Organisation\`

It seems like Outlook is removing all closing parenthesis from the display name and I also tried using brackets, but the closing bracket also disappears. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, i found that sender address will be hid in the more information card, we just need to hover over mouse to sender's name and the address with be shown under contact information.

Comment: I know how to find the sender's name. It just that it's missing the closing parenthesis

Comment: I'm afraid that email addresses are not shown for internal (Exchange) messages.

Comment: Those are external emails, not internal emails. Are you familiar with [aliases in outlook.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-an-email-alias-in-outlook-com-459b1989-356d-40fa-a689-8f285b13f1f2) or [aliases in Gmail](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9437157?hl=en)?